# ionic - how to go to a list and select and return back to the original with the selected value

Tags: list, cordova, ionic-framework, onclick, navigation

I am trying to accomplish this using ionic/cordova:

on button press

goes to a new screen with a list

selects an item in the list

and returns to the original with the selected value.

Can someone give directions how to accomplish this and give an example how this is accomplished ? Thanks.

Comment: almost solve in this but still have some issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523712/ionic-how-to-detect-and-pass-value-back-to-original-view-with-ionichistory-go

Answer (score 0):

**Please** provide what you have already tried. However, I understand what you want:

Make sure all your pages/templates are set up inside app.js correctly, have a controller.js, and services.js.

Passing data between controllers is done through services, You can inject the service into each page's controller and using `set()` and `get()` methods to change and receive the value(s) accordingly.

HTML (First page):

```
<ion-view view-title="firstPage">
    <ion-content>
        <!-- Binds selected value to div -->
        <div ng-bind="selected.selec"> </div>
        <!-- Goes to next page -->
        <button class="button" ng-click="next()">
            Next
        </button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller (First):

```
.controller('firstPageCtrl', function($scope, $state, savedList) {
    // Go to next page
    $scope.next = function() { $state.go("secPage"); }

    // Get selected value from service, savedList
    $scope.selected = { selec: "" };
    $scope.selected.selec = savedList.get();
})
```

HTML (Second Page):

```
<ion-view view-title="secPage">
    <ion-content>
        <!-- Radio buttons will only allow one value to be selected at one time -->
        <ion-list>
            <!-- Pass in value of radio button to update function -->
            <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'A'" ng-change="update('A')">Choose A</ion-radio>
            <ion-radio ng-model="choice" ng-value="'B'" ng-change="update('B')">Choose B</ion-radio>
        </ion-list>
        <!-- Goes back to first page -->
        <button class="button" ng-click="back()">
            Go Back
        </button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller (Second):

```
.controller('secPageCtrl', function($scope, $state, savedList) {
    $scope.back = function() { $state.go("firstPage"); }

    // Send selected value to service, savedList
    $scope.update = function(selec) { 
        savedList.set(selec); 
    }
})
```

Service:

```
.factory('savedList', function() {
    var selec = "";

    // Sets selec to what ever is passed in
    function set(data) {
        selec = data;
    }
    // Returns selec
    function get() {
        return selec;
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
})
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services