# Ionic - How to detect and pass value back to original view with $ionicHistory.goBack();

Tags: list, cordova, ionic-framework, parameter-passing, back

Using ionic, I am trying to have a use case to select from a list and return back to the original view with some value. I'ved already done most of the part except detecting it has returned to the original view and passing a value back to the original view.

Here's so far what i'ved accomplished:

button that goes to a list

```
    <button class="button button-block button-outline button-positive" ng-click="performselectUnit()"> Select Unit
    </button>
```

this is the trigger to go to the new view with the list

```
$scope.performselectUnit = function(){
  console.log('performselectUnit');

  $state.go('app.units');
}
```

the view with list when press performs an action on the selected row

```
  <ion-item collection-repeat="unit in units" class="item item-icon-right item-icon-left" ng-click="selectUnit(unit.id)">
```

on selection of the row it goes back to the original view with $ionicHistory.goBack()

```
  $scope.selectUnit = function(unit_id){
  console.log('performselectUnit:' + unit_id);

  $ionicHistory.goBack();
}
```

From the last function, how do detect its gone back to the original view and pass some value.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I tried this.

Broadcast the result

```
  $scope.selectUnit = function(unit_id){
      console.log('performselectUnit:' + unit_id);

      $ionicHistory.goBack();
      $rootScope.$broadcast('selected-unit', { data: unit_id });


    }
```

in the original view controller i capture the event and result.

```
$rootScope.$on('selected-unit', function(event, args) {
    console.log("received selected-unit" + args.data);
    $scope.showSelectedUnit = args.data;
});
```

but it NEVER got updated in the view

```
<label class="item item-text-wrap">
    <button class="button button-block button-outline button-positive" ng-click="performselectUnit()"> Select Unit
    </button>
    {{showSelectedUnit}}
</label>
```

How can I get it to update in the view ? or is there a better way

Comment: can please create a fiddle for this? it will easy to reproduce the problem. In the meantime try to call `$scope.apply();` after `$scope.showSelectedUnit = args.data;`, see that works (y)

Comment: im getting it work with $stateParams, that way it will get passed. let me do some tests on this.

Answer (score 1):

Faced to the exact same issue, I could make it work by switching the order of calls to goBack and broadcast:

```
   $rootScope.$broadcast('selected-unit', { data: unit_id });   
   $ionicHistory.goBack();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pub-sub service for sharing info between two ctrl

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/uxusk19z/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope, datasharer) {
 $scope.sharedData = datasharer.getSharedData();
 $scope.send = function() {
    datasharer.setSharedData($scope.name);    
 }
}

function My2Ctrl($scope, datasharer) {
  function getSendData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.sharedData = data;
  }

 datasharer.registerForSharedData(getSendData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$rootScope.$on` should resolve your problem indeed, just use `$scope.$apply` in `$rootScope.$on`:

```
$rootScope.$on('selected-unit', function(event, args) {
    console.log("received selected-unit" + args.data);
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.showSelectedUnit = args.data;
    });
});
```

What's more, the `$rootScope.$broadcast` is always expensive, so you could try `$rootScope.$emit` instead. More about angular event, please refer to https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/.
But the more graceful solution is use `Service` to share data between controllers, you could refer to [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers).